# Move div on windows resize

Tags: html, css

I want to relocate `divA` below `divB` but i just cant get it. I've tried using float which it seems its the solution for this but it still doesn't work.

Here is  is my CSS code:

```
.tweet-box{
  position:fixed;
  top: 140px;
  left: 75px;
  float: left;
  width:100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="logo"></div>    
<div id="div1">
Some content
</div>
<div id="div2">
Some content
</div>
```

Example:

[image: eg]

Comment: Any css for div1 and div2?

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap both `#div1` and `#div2` inside a common parent, with `display:flex` and specify different order below the device width of your choice (`768px` in the example below):

```css
.reorder-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
#div1, #div2 {
  border: 2px solid red;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
#logo {
  text-align: center;
}

#div2 {
    order: -1;
  }
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .reorder-wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #div2 {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">This is logo</div>
<div class="reorder-wrapper">
  <div id="div1">
    Some content: #div1
  </div>
  <div id="div2">
    Some content: #div2
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** this is not the only way to do it and, based on your needs another technique might be better for the result. You need to update your question with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you have trouble applying the above principle to your case.

Comment: Is there any way you can privately help me?

Comment: @MiguelBetancourt, you can find my website in my profile and it has a contact form. While the contact form works, the website is no longer expressing my current state as a developer. I've relocated in Dublin since I put that website up and I'm not currently available for hire. I'll probably update it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Create a parent element and make it display:flex; and adjust direction of flex according to it. Use media queries for responsive. `.parent-div { display:flex; }`